# returning an empty initializer list as default value for a function

Tags: c++

keeping with DRY, I want to avoid repeating the return type of a function returning a default value:

```
Foo bar()
{
    return Foo{};  // shouldn't be necessary to respecify Foo here.
}
```

I tried a few things and ended up with this construct:

```
Foo bar()
{
    return {};
}
```

which seems to be a return expression from list-initialization. Which I expect is equivalent to calling return Foo{{}}. My question is, is this a thing? because I haven't often seen it used and it feels like it would be pretty convenient.

Comment: My main concern here would be readability, do people find this easy to read?

Comment: In my opinion, it should be equivalent to `Foo({})` or `Foo()`, depending on the constructors of `Foo`. What is this `Foo{{}}` thing?

Comment: @Lingxi passes `{}` to Foo's constructor (or initializes first member if Foo is an aggregate). Worse than `Foo{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Foo bar()
{
    return {};
}
```

That is perfect, and succinct! It will work as long as the default constructor is not declared to be `explicit`.

However, if you have this:

```
explicit Foo(); //though practically it doesn't make much sense to me!
```

then `return {};` wont work, and you have to write `return Foo{};` instread.